# Scala large document split

Tags: scala, split, bigdata, data-extraction

I have a large tagged document (>10Gb) containing some text data.

```html
<ID>some TXT I</ID>
<NAME>name 1</NAME>
<TYPE>type1</TYPE>
<DESCRIPTION>loooots of data, 
html and 

stuff

....
</DESCRIPTION>

<ID>some TXT II</ID>
<NAME>name 2</NAME>
<TYPE>type2</TYPE>
<DESCRIPTION>loooots of data, 
html and 

stuff

....
</DESCRIPTION>

<ID>some TXT 3</ID>
<NAME>name 3</NAME>
<TYPE>type3</TYPE>
<DESCRIPTION>loooots of data, 
html and 
other
stuff

....
</DESCRIPTION>
```

In order to process the data I wanted to divide it into chunks without reading all the data to memory. I have a solution for smaller files but using mkString on the monster ruins my runtime and causes java out of memory;)

```
   val arrayOfPages: ParSeq[Page] = file.mkString.split("\\n<URL>")
  .toStream.par.map(_.trim).filter(!_.isEmpty)
  .map(e => "<URL>" + e).map{parsePage}
```

Any other idea how to bit it? 
I need to have a iterator or stream of these objects that I could process them lazily.

Comment: How about [parsing this XML as Using SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) - you don't need to load it fully, so it will not consume so much memory.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I only want to parse my structure but in DESCRIPTION tag there could be large embedded html with javascript and other stuff I do not want to parse, just store it to the string and put the the structure as a property. I haven't seen any example of customizing SAX to fulfill this requirement? Parsing this doc with SAX would throw a lot of exceptions as the html is bad with a lot of not escaped special chars ,amps and references

Comment: Sure, SAX is just the way how to parse XML. But with SAX you can get DESCRIPTION tag and try to find your data inside this tag ("\\n<URL>"), not in the whole file - so it should be ok by memory.